# i want to get data from controller to view can you help me

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

```
   public JsonResult GetItemCode(string Code)
        {
            double Category = objFatchXEntities.ItemCardUAE.Single(s => s.Code == Code).Price;
            
            return Json(Category, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
```

Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'double?' to 'double'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 1):

It is because your query returns double?. You can change type for Category but better to use var

```
var category = objFatchXEntities.....
 return Json(category, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

but it is always better idea to check for null

```
var category = objFatchXEntities.ItemCardUAE.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Code == Code);

if (category == null || category.Price==null) return null;

 return Json(category.Price, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: show new error System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: @AhmedHamed where is the error? I expected category=null it should return null

Comment: i try category=null not get Price so i try to use
var category = objFatchXEntities.....
 return Json(category, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Answer (score 1):

You declared a double variable, it expects a double not a nullable double. You could either get the value of the `double?` so you have matching types like this

```
double Category = objFatchXEntities.ItemCardUAE.Single(s => s.Code == Code).Price.Value;
```

But the problem with this is that you get a NullReference error if price is null at any point. You could just check if Price has a value before doing anything like this

```
if (objFatchXEntities.ItemCardUAE.Single(s => s.Code == Code).Price.HasValue)
{
    ... do something 
}
```